# Is it possible to use dynamic values for a query with the BETWEEN keyword?

Tags: sql, postgresql

My PostgreSQL DB contains transactions for users who have yearly or monthly subscriptions. I want to get an active count of users on each day for an entire month. My schema contains columns with timestamp (in unix) and the type of plan a specific user has.

My thought process is querying the count of users in the past month with a monthly subscription and the same for the yearly subscribers, but in the past year.

For one day, the query is simple. To do this for each day in the month, however, I would have to dynamically update the values in the BETWEEN clause to get an accurate count. Is there a way to do this?

schema:

timestamp | user_email | event_name | plan_name | total_amount | overage_amount

Sample data (1 user):

| timestamp | email | event_name | plan_name | total_amount | overage_amount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1530417600 | "test@email.com" | "Signup" | "Monthly" | 0 | 0 |
| 1530460800 | "test@email.com" | "Trial" | "Monthly" | 0 | 0 |
| 1530720000 | "test@email.com" | "Recurring" | "Monthly" | 1000 | 0 |
| 1533398400 | "test@email.com" | "Recurring" | "Monthly" | 1100 | 100 |
| 1534694400 | "test@email.com" | "Upgrade" | "Yearly" | 9568 | 68 |
| 1542646800 | "test@email.com" | "Overage" | "Yearly" | 123 | 123 |
| 1553011200 | "test@email.com" | "Overage" | "Yearly" | 321 | 321 |
| 1566230400 | "test@email.com" | "Recurring" | "Yearly" | 10100 | 100 |
| 1597852800 | "test@email.com" | "Recurring" | "Yearly" | 10000 | 0 |
| 1597932000 | "test@email.com" | "Refund" | "Yearly" | -10000 | 0 |

Expected result:

Given a year and month, I want to generate the current amount of active users each day of that month and year.

```
[

   { dayOfMonth: 1, total: 50 }

            .

            .

            .

   {dayOfMonth: 30, total: 70}

]
```

Comment: I don't use postgresql, but would suggest looking into [generate_series()](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/functions-srf.html) . It can be used to generate daily dates, for example https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=44fa852b5cc26529a8502d3eb0bd312d  . There's also a good ole calendar table.

Comment: Can you provide your table structure including some sample data related to this question and expected result?

Comment: Does the sample data represent separate rows or some sort of json string? If it's rows, please put it in table format for clarity. Use tools like https://ozh.github.io/ascii-tables/.  That said, if it's rows, a join with generate_series() should work.

Comment: So, you have a single row in JSON format that stores all your users? Or is each user stored as a single JSON object. I also don't see a "timestamp" in the JSON data although your column names seem to indicate you have one.

Comment: It was in json originally, so it was easier to just copy and paste that data. I now realize that the format was confusing, so it is now updated. The data is in a postgres db and the timestamp is the first column of each row (in unix). Each user transaction is stored as a single row.

Comment: What happened when you tried using generate_series()?

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to *dynamically* update your values. Instead you can calculate/generate the dates for the year-month parameter using the `make_date(...)` and `generate_series(...)` functions then join your table converting your unix timestamp (assumption, you really should convert and store as actual timestamp). You wind up with something like: (see [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=af06910fab24f9556030449849a30586))

```
with parms( p_year, p_month) as 
     ( values (2018,08) )                --- given year, month
    -- with given year, month build each day for that period
   , dt_range (date_range) as 
     ( select generate_series ( make_date (p_year, p_month, 1)
                              , (make_date  (p_year, p_month, 1) + interval '1 month' - interval '1 day')::date
                              , interval '1 day'
                              )::date 
         from parms
     ) 
-- get date, daily_totalm daily_overage for each day in month
select d.date_range                    "Date" 
     , coalesce(sum(total_amount),0)   "Daily Total"
     , coalesce(sum(overage_amount),0) "Daily Overage"
  from dt_range  d 
  left join test t 
         on  to_timestamp(t.u_timestamp)::date = d.date_range
  group by d.date_range
  order by d.date_range;
```

Comment: this is a great solution to getting the revenue per day, but I already have a solution to this... my current issue is getting the number of active users per day (monthly and yearly combined).  i.e for each day in the month, getting the count of yearly subscribers in the past 364 days (for each day, which is why i thought the query had to be dynamic) and add it the count of yearly subs who subscribed that day. (the same for monthly subs but for those who subscribed in the past month, instead of year). the total between the two would give the number of active users, which is what i'm looking for

Comment: Getting the *current amount of active users each day of that month and year* you only need to remove the ` coalesce(...)` functions and replace with the single `count (distinct email)` (since nothing else seems to identify a user in the data posted). Getting the remainder is a **totally different question entirely**. However, the date manipulation would be similar.   You need to **update your question with the above description and post the expected results of your data**.